# How to pivot a field into two seperate fields based on condition

Tags: sql, filter, pivot

I'm looking for some assistance with the following issue. I am looking for the the most elegant way to do this, as my current method really is not nice, at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated :

I have this:

```
cnumber     cid         prim
n100        123123      y         
n100        465488      n         
n123        798         y         
n768        544         y         
n455        123         y         
n455        098         n
```

I am looking to get this:

```
cnumber     y           n         
n100        123123      465488
n123        798         NULL
n768        544         NULL
n455        123         98
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select cnumber,
       max(case when prim = 'y' then cid end) as y,
       max(case when prim = 'n' then cid end) as n
from t
group by cnumber;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon.

You are both a gentleman and a scholar! This is a MUCH nicer solution than the one I currently have.

Hope you have a great week,
Thanks